# Using active trail as url path

Tags: path-aliases, routes

I would like to use the active trail menu as url path by altering pathauto?

Can this be performed?

Comment: What is the "active trail menu"?

Comment: talkink about the active trail.

Comment: What i want is to use pathauto_alias_alter

Comment: I have been building websites for a long time. "Active trail" is not a term I have ever heard used. Do you mean the current path? If so you need to add more details about what you are doing. Because if you have a site, you build your paths, then you build your menu. No need for pathauto_alias_alter.

Comment: Active trail is part of the menu system. It tracks where in the menu the user's current page is.